# Authenticating an ASP.NET Core WebAPI using an ASP.NET Core MVC with Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have two web applications: one **ASP.NET Core MVC Website** and one **ASP.NET Core Web API** (using ASP.NET Core 2.1).

I authenticate the users in the website using Azure AD. When I pass the access_token from the website to the API (using the Authorization header with "Bearer access_token"); I have this error:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException:
>   IDX10503: **Signature validation failed**. Keys tried:
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey , KeyId: ... '.

I don't understand why.

Here is the configuration of the Website:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = "aad";
    o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
{
    o.Authority = azureAdsettings.Authority;
    o.Audience = azureAdsettings.ClientId;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect("aad", o =>
{
    o.Authority = azureAdsettings.Authority;
    o.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
    o.ClientId = azureAdsettings.ClientId;
    o.ClientSecret = azureAdsettings.ClientSecret;
    o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
    o.SaveTokens = true;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = azureAdsettings.Authority
    };
    o.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx =>
        {
            TokenProvider tokenProvider = (TokenProvider)ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenProvider>();
            await tokenProvider.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(ctx);
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Error");
            context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };
});
```

And here is the configuration of the API:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = this.Configuration["AzureAd:Authority"];
    options.Audience = this.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = ValidateIssuer;
});
```

The **azureAdsettings** object is exaclty the same in both appsettings.json.

The authentication on the website seems to work nicely. I can get the authorization code and retreive access token.

Comment: Can you check what is the audience of the token? You can paste the access token at https://jwt.ms. The `aud` claim will tell you who the token is meant for. In your API's case it should be its client id (since that is what you have configured as the valid audience).

Comment: The aud is "https://graph.microsoft.com". How can I configure the audience when acquiring the token? Is this related to the scope requested (in my case: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default")?

Comment: Yes :D You asked for a token to call MS Graph API, and then use it to call your API. Your API should have its own identifier.

Comment: Is it even possible to pass a token to the WebAPI and use the access_token to authenticate Users inside the API? I use the MSAL library and just stumbled upon this issue on Github : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/446. If I want to call the API which scopes do I need to set (without graph api, multiple resources doesn't seem to work either)?

Comment: Essentially if the API is defined on the same app, you use the id token :)

Comment: I successfully called the API from the website. Your old post helped me a lot https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad! Thx ! Now, I'm trying to call the graph api inside my own API but without any success.  I have the error "Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50013: The token issuer doesn't match the api version: A version 1 token cannot be used with the v2 endpoint". If you know what it means... I'm pretty sure, I'm using the v2 endpoint for the authorize.

Comment: I've seen that before.. Could you try putting an Id token here: https://jwt.ms? If it says Azure AD V1 token, then I might know why the error happens. In that case the Id tokens are not v2 tokens (for whatever reason), and you can't use that with On-Behalf-Of. In that case one work-around would be to get the Graph access token in your MVC app..

Comment: Yes it says AD V1 token. But I pass the access token to the API (not the id token). Finally, I created two different apps (with 2 differents clientId).

Comment: Do you know why I got a V1 token instead of the V2?

Comment: Not sure :/ It might be that there is something not quite implemented in v2.

Comment: I tried my luck here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/575 :)